# Measure and display power consumption of DC motor

Tags: breadboard, 7segmentdisplay

My daughter wants to be able to measure the power being used by a small motor under different loads as part of an A-level engineering project.

Ideally this would be displayed in 7-segment display(s).

I have seen power measuring IC (eg https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/energy-measurement-ics/7165873 ) - they generally seem to output to a microprocessor. I don’t know if there is something that can incorporate this and just provide a 7-segment compatible driver.

She only has to make a prototype and I was hoping to do this on a solderless breadboard.

It’s been a long time since I did anything like this, so it’s possible things have moved on significantly

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: That's a very cool project for students. Does the assignment call for displaying of power (watts) or current (amps)?

Comment: Get an Arduino. Use two of its ADC input channels to measure motor current and voltage respectively. Get a compatible text or 7 segment display, find the library to drive it for minimal driving code effort.

Comment: If you want to see the results in watt, that requires multiplication which screams for an MCU. How about a commercial offering https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-6-5-100V-Voltmeter-Multimeter-Amperage/dp/B079JVGRSL

Comment: Is measuring the power the point of the project, or is building a gadget to measure the power the point of the project?

Comment: "**She**...has to make a prototype and **I** was hoping to do this..." Perhaps it would be better if your daughter asked here and matched the project to her own skill level.

Comment: @anrieff displaying of power in watts

Comment: the project is to illustrate how moving a fulcrum/lever/mass affects the work done (by a motor), the suggestion of @winny is looking pretty good for a prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this IC has SPI interface for communication with outer world.

Without MCU you are able to communicate with this chip using 8bit shift registers. For simplification it is better to have separate shift registers, one for sending a commands and another for reading the data.

The output data are 8bit number so you will need another chip for translating binary to digits.

You can make a clock generator from 555 + 4017 for sending eight Clk edges and then stop.

If you are interested in basic usage of this IC only like reading the real power in one second intervals then this isnt a big deal. Once you set the IC at beginning then just send a command in loop for reading the power data.

Btw, the active power can be read at E1 pin with frequency to voltage  converter (freq. on E1 pin is proportional to act. power) so no clock and shift reg. are needed.

So you must consider if using of 5 or 6 chips is solution for you or to make it done with one MCU.

For advanced usage of this IC you would also need EEPROM for storing the Command Codes etc..  so number of chips necessary will extremely rise.

On other hand for imagination all communication with this IC can be done even with buttons and Leds only (no any other chip), but you would have to click too much - generating Clk edges, setting commands to send and so.. and also remember the Led sequence from SDO pin to get the data you want and translate it.

Comment: my daughter's teacher is trying to steer them away from an Arduino because he cannot help with it, but this answer gives her something to go back with.

Answer (score 0):

> *Any advice much appreciated*

If you were just interested in converting a voltage signal to be used by a 7-segment display then [this device](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/809385.pdf) is pretty handy and still commonly available: -

[image]

> **The TC7107A drives common anode light emitting diode (LED) displays
> directly with 8 mA per segment.**

So, that gets you from the analogue domain to the 7-segment domain and, if all you want to do at that point is measure current (not power) consumption, it's a fairly easy next step. But, if you want power (voltage x current) then you can use a PWM based analogue multiplier. This is a 4 quadrant version and I'm showing how you can square a signal input: -

[image]

Proof waveform of squared input: -

[image]

But, given that you are only needing a single quadrant multiplication of volts and amps, it's a bit simpler than the above. Here's a single quadrant multiplier that squares a triangle wave: -

[image]

And, as you can see, it does it effectively: -

[image]

Red is the input waveform (a triangle wave starting at 0 volts and peaking at 5 volts). Blue is the circuit output and, superimposed in purple is the theoretical squared-input.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to write this, but I think it's way out my and my daughter's capability at the moment